# How do I set a regex for a URL group like this?

Tags: regex, url, web-scraping

I would like to set a regex for a url group like this:

It starts with this page,

```
https://www.cartoonmad.com/comic/6341.html
```

Then it goes on like these,

```
https://www.cartoonmad.cc/comic/634100012013001.html
https://www.cartoonmad.cc/comic/634100012013002.html
https://www.cartoonmad.cc/comic/634100012013003.html
....
```

So you can see the pattern is simple, it starts with "https://www.cartoonmad.com/comic/6341", and then goes on in a serial manner like "00012013001", "00012013002", "00012013003"...

So how do i set a regen for that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using regex:

```
re.match('^\d$',text) - One digit

re.match('^\d+$',text) - More than one digit
```

### Explanation

```
^ - Starts with 
\d - digit 
+ - more than one digit 
$ - End
```

### Alternative Solution

This isn't what you're looking for but also works, using f-strings. I'm using 10 in this case as just an example but

### Code Example

```
for i in range(10):
    url = f'https://www.cartoonmad.cc/comic/63410001201300{i}.html
    print(url)
```

### Output

```
 https://www.cartoonmad.cc/comic/634100012013000.html
 https://www.cartoonmad.cc/comic/634100012013001.html
 https://www.cartoonmad.cc/comic/634100012013002.html
 https://www.cartoonmad.cc/comic/634100012013003.html
 https://www.cartoonmad.cc/comic/634100012013004.html
 https://www.cartoonmad.cc/comic/634100012013005.html
 https://www.cartoonmad.cc/comic/634100012013006.html
 https://www.cartoonmad.cc/comic/634100012013007.html
 https://www.cartoonmad.cc/comic/634100012013008.html
 https://www.cartoonmad.cc/comic/634100012013009.html
```

### Explanation

1. Using f-strings, by putting an f before the string, we can use the placeholder `{}`, to hold a variable of our choice. In this case I choose `i` but this could be anything.
2. We then loop over i, in this case from 0 to 9, and it generates the URLs.

Comment: thank you @AaronS, I appreciate it! Yes you are right, even though it is not the answer which i am looking for right now, but it is a good reference later when i go back to Python, and do something like that.

Comment: Ah! I assumed python based on you were using it for web-scraping! My apologies. The regex I've given you should work though for digits. I've updated it because you may only want one digit.

Comment: you are right! I am python based, and i am a big fan of it! haha! Just the work i am doing isn't python, lol . My bad, i didn't mention it .